# Is $\int_{-2}^3\frac{1}{x^3}dx=\frac5{72}$ or not defined?

Tags: calculus, integration

If we divide it into two parts such that $$I=\int_{-2}^0\frac{1}{x^3}dx+\int_0^3\frac{1}{x^3}dx$$

And then use substitution $x=-t$ we get $$I=\int_2^3\frac1{x^3}dx=\frac5{72}$$

However, If we use limits on both part separately, they both diverge, so the integral diverges too.

Which explanation is correct?

Comment: See [Cauchy principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).

Comment: @ChenWang: expand this into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that the integral is not defined (because of the singularity), so you can't trust what the anti-derivative tells you. It's even worse with $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=-2\tag{1}$$

The area is clearly positive ($+\infty$). If you were to break up $(1)$ you would get $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}dx=2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x^2}dx\rightarrow\infty$$ So it's not always true that you can break up integrals.

Comment: Indeed, the area is positive, the problem is that it is infinite

Comment: The OP is *not* blindly applying the anti-derivative, so this seems to miss the point. The point is that the integral of an odd, integrable function over an interval symmetric about the origin is zero. Can this be extended to functions with a singularity at the origin? In the strict sense, no; but in the [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) sense, yes. This is why I encouraged Chen Wang to expand their comment into an answer.

Comment: @robjohn Integral of odd integrable symmetric function is equal to zero in strict sense or Cauchy Princicple Sense?

Comment: Also, what about $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^3dx$$, $0$ or not defined?

Comment: @AFalseName: "... the integral of an odd, integrable function over an interval symmetric about the origin is zero. Can this be extended to functions with a singularity at the origin? In the strict sense, no; but in the Cauchy Principal Value sense, yes." Does this not cover the first of your comments? The Cauchy Principal Value might cover the second case if you consider the [one point compactification of the reals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compactification_(mathematics)#Alexandroff_one-point_compactification).

Answer (score 1):

On account of the singularity at $x=0$, the integral you give is undefined. The only way you could get close is with:
$$\int_{-2}^{3}{[x^{-3}dx]}\approx\int_{-2}^{-\epsilon}{[x^{-3}dx]}+\int_{\epsilon}^{3}{[x^{-3}dx]}$$
With $\epsilon$ as a very small positive constant.

Comment: With a bit more rigor, what you are suggesting here is called [Cauchy Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value).